# Other ways to create line animation

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create a animation that runs around a shape. The method I came up with is similar to the snake game, drawing the desired part and refresh it with white screen.

For example, if I want to draw a linear line animation, with the max animated length of 3:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
dummy_lst = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
colored_position = [[1,1,1], [1,1,2], [1,2,3], [2,3,3], [3,3,3]] # if the numbers overlapped, it draws the same place which is fine
```

and then I iterate the colored_position to get the animation done.

The real code:

```
import pygame
import sys

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
CELLSIZE = 10

x, y = 150, 200

position = [[x+CELLSIZE*i, y] for i in range(50)] +\
           [[x+CELLSIZE*50, y+CELLSIZE*i] for i in range(50)] +\
           [[x+CELLSIZE*50-CELLSIZE*i, y+CELLSIZE*50]for i in range(50)] +\
           [[x, y+CELLSIZE*50-CELLSIZE*i]for i in range(50)]


# creates fake firsts and lasts
def dummy_list(list, length):
    return [list[0]]*(length-1) + list + [list[-1]]*(length-1)


def main():
    pygame.init()

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_WIDTH))

    count = 0
    while True:
        clock.tick(10)

        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        dummy = dummy_list(position, 50)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit() 
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    count = 0
                    while count < 1:   # I could chaget this to see many times it rotates
                        for i in range(len(dummy)-50+1):
                            for j in range(9): # change this to adjust how wide the colored part is 
                                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), pygame.Rect(
                                    dummy[i+j][0], dummy[i+j][1], CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE), 0)
                                pygame.display.update()
                            screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
                        count += 1
        pygame.display.update()
```

But it seems very hard-coding. since I have to know each part of the desired position's Xs and Ys. What's the smarter way to complete the task?

Comment: You want to move the object along a path. How else do you want to define the path than by points?

Comment: I was thinking if there's build-in method to create this kind of movement, instead of having to hard-code this way. Let's say I want to create the same animation for a circle, it's gonna be troublesome. Also notice it has a "pause" between loops  and I'd also like to fix that ( I mean it auto continue the second round without finishing the first one)

Comment: *"also like to fix that"* This is a new question. 1 question per post. Anyway this is unclear. If you want to move in a circle you must write a function that generates the points along a circle.

Answer (score 0):

You want to move the object along a path. I don't see any problem in defining the path through a list of points.
However you can write a function that generates the list of points from a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object:

```py
def generate_positions(rect, step):
    return [[x, rect.top] for x in range(rect.left, rect.right, step)] +\
           [[rect.right, y] for y in range(rect.top, rect.bottom, step)] +\
           [[x, rect.bottom] for x in range(rect.right, rect.left, -step)] +\
           [[rect.left, y] for y in range(rect.bottom, rect.top, -step)]

CELLSIZE = 10
x, y = 150, 200
position = generate_positions(pygame.Rect(x, y, 50*CELLSIZE, 50*CELLSIZE), CELLSIZE)
```

---

I recommend to use the application loop to draw the snake:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import sys

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800

def generate_positions(rect, step):
    return [[x, rect.top] for x in range(rect.left, rect.right, step)] +\
           [[rect.right, y] for y in range(rect.top, rect.bottom, step)] +\
           [[x, rect.bottom] for x in range(rect.right, rect.left, -step)] +\
           [[rect.left, y] for y in range(rect.bottom, rect.top, -step)]

CELLSIZE = 10
x, y = 150, 200
position = generate_positions(pygame.Rect(x, y, 10*CELLSIZE, 10*CELLSIZE), CELLSIZE)
    
def main():
    pygame.init()

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_WIDTH))

    current_point = None
    snake_len = 9
    while True:
        clock.tick(10)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit() 
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    current_point = -snake_len

        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

        if current_point != None:
            for i in range(max(0, current_point), min(len(position), current_point+snake_len)):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), pygame.Rect(*position[i], CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE), 0)
            current_point += 1
            if current_point >= len(position):
                current_point = None
            
        pygame.display.update()

main()
```